# Sunspot / Solr full text search - how to index Rails associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, solr, sunspot

Is it possible to index through an association with Sunspot?

For example, if a Customer has_many Contacts, I want a 'searchable' block on my Customer model that indexes the Contact#first_name and Contact#last_name columns for use in searches on Customer.

acts_as_solr has an :include option for this. I've simply been combining the associated column names into a text field on Customer like shown below, but this doesn't seem very flexible.

```
searchable do
text :organization_name, :default_boost => 2
text :billing_address1, :default_boost => 2
text :contact_names do
  contacts.map { |contact| contact.to_s }
end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know how would you boost contact_names?

Comment: text :contact_names, :default_boost => 2

Comment: Related follow-up question:
How to not re-query associations:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516281/not-re-querying-has-and-belongs-to-many-associations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's exactly how to do it. Solr is essentially document-oriented, so any data that comes from associations in your database is flattened down into your document. An :include option is just mild sugar which ends up doing the same thing that you do here.

Comment: Interesting, that's kind of what I thought. Going with the same example, can I sort the Customer result set by Contact#last_name in some way?

Comment: Does the :include option speed things up at all? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
searchable do
  string :sort_contact_name do
    contacts.map { |contact| contact.last_name }.sort.first
  end
end
```

Then you can sort by the :sort_contact_name field. Note that I had to reduce the set of contact names to a single name, as Solr can only sort on fields that have a single value per document (which makes sense when you think about it).