# Problems to search ActsAsTaggableOn with sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on, sunspot-rails

I've setup sunspot and I'm searching fine in my `Place.name` field

Now I want to search by "acts as taggable" tags

I've setup two contexts to taggable, categories

with this model and controller I'm not getting any errors but when I search for my tag name sunspot doesn't return any results.

I've run `rake sunspot:reindex` and `rake sunspot:solr:reindex` but no change.

When I run `Place.last.categories` in rails console I only get one array `["Category one","Category 2"]`

Model

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  searchable :auto_index => true, :auto_remove => true  do
    text :name, :stored => true
    string :category_list, :multiple => true, :stored => true
  end


  acts_as_votable   
  acts_as_mappable :default_units => :kms,
                   :lat_column_name => :latitude,
                   :lng_column_name => :longitude


  validates_presence_of :name , :state, :city, :neighborhood, :adress,:latitude, :longitude

  belongs_to :user

  acts_as_ordered_taggable_on :categories, :obstacles



end
```

Controller

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_place, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote, :downvote, :favorite]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  # GET /places
  # GET /places.json
  def index
    @search = Place.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
    end  
    @places = @search.results
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should add `searchable` block in your tag model.In my memory,the tag model may have assoiations,if you want to know more about how to  index Rails associations,you may checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615535/sunspot-solr-full-text-search-how-to-index-rails-associations)